# How do you apply the first uniqueness theorem for Laplace's equation if your volume has two surfaces?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

So, for example, instead of a spherical volume centered at the origin with $r<a$, you could have  a spherical shell with $a<r<b$. Now the volume has two surfaces: an internal one and an external one. What happens to the first uniqueness theorem now?

Answer (score 1):

The proof for the first uniqueness theorem works regardless of the number of  disconnected components the region's boundary has.  The difference between two solutions also obeys Laplace's equation, and is equal to zero at all points on all the components of the boundary.  Since Laplace's equation has no local maxima or minima, this implies that the "difference function" is zero everywhere in the interior.